# How does function-style cast syntax work?

Tags: c++, casting

I guess I am a bit puzzled by the syntax. What does the following mean?

```
typedef char *PChar;
hopeItWorks = PChar( 0x00ff0000 );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is equivalent to `(PChar) 0x00ff0000` or `(char *) 0x00ff0000`. Syntactically think of it as invoking a one-argument constructor.

Answer (score 5):

`SomeType(args)` means explicit constructor call if `SomeType` is user-defined type and usual c-cast `(SomeType)args` if `SomeType` is fundamental type or a pointer.

`PChar` is equivalent to `char *` (pointer). Thus `hopeItWorks = (char *)0x00ff0000;`

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef char *PChar;
```

Its typedef of `char*` to `Pchar`. Instead of using `char*` you can define variables with Pchar.

```
hopeItWorks = PChar( 0x00ff0000 );
```

Its equivalent to ==>

```
 hopeItWorks = (char *)( 0x00ff0000 );
```