# Issue with type casting the argument of the constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(int d) : x(d) {}
    int x;
};

int main() 
{ 
    double x = 3.14;

    Foo f( int(x) );

    std::cout << f.x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code I get the following error:

> [Error] request for member 'x' in 'f', which is of non-class type 'Foo(int)'

Suppose that in `int main` I remove `int` in `Foo f(int(x))`. 
I mean if I write just like this:

```
     Foo f(x);
```

the code compiled correctly and got the output as 3.

So what happens if we type cast the argument like **Foo f(int(x))** to invoke the constructor?

Comment: Look up "Most vexing parse"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo f(int(x));`

It is not a type cast, it's a function declaration - function `f` that takes an `int` called `x` and returns a `Foo`.

The grammar allows a (theoretically unlimited) set of parentheses around an identifier in a declaration. It is the same as if you wrote

```
Foo f(int x);
```

or

```
Foo f( int (((x))) );
```

As you already figured out, you don't need to cast, as conversion between a `double` and and `int` is implicit. But if you really wanted, you could say `static_cast<int>(x)` instead or

```
Foo f((int (x)));
//    ^       ^
```

which makes it an expression instead of declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get an error, I get a warning

```
C4930: 'Foo f(int)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)
```

Try this instead:

```
Foo1 f1(int(pi));
```

and look up the most vexing parse, as suggested in the comments. You have declared a function, rather than called the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`int(x)` isn't how you properly cast. `(int)(x)` or `(int)x` will work for your particular case, I believe. Start with that and then let us know if you're still having problems.

Comment: Is it really incorrect? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594187/how-does-function-style-cast-syntax-work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474933/what-exactly-is-or-was-the-purpose-of-c-function-style-casts, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles

Comment: `int(x)` casts `x` to type `int`.

Comment: Perhaps avoiding c-style casts will make the problem go away.

Comment: I stand corrected. I didn't realize it was C-style - but I feel like it probably still shouldn't be done this way just to keep things simple. But at this point, that's just my opinion.